# How to instrument Rails app and identify memory/performance bottleneck?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, ruby-on-rails-3, instrumentation

How have people instrumented or analyzed Rails apps to identify culprits in performance, either in terms of speed or memory usage?

Comment: There are third party tools available, and New Relic is one: http://www.newrelic.com/  -- I have no affiliation with New Relic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly suggest checking out NewRelic.

You can use it for free in [developer mode.](http://support.newrelic.com/kb/docs/developer-mode) Watch the [screencast](http://www.newrelic.com/demos/developer-mode.html) and I'm sure you'll be sold.